# JUnit execute all test classes of all packages

Tags: java, junit

Is there any way to build all test cases of JUnit at once?Like on "Ruby on rails" by the command "rake test" all test classes got executed. For Java I saw some solutions of executing all tests within a package. but I want to execute all test cases for all packages. Is it possible? how should I do on the build.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run all tests or specific tests filtered by package name or class name.
Here is an example of `<batchtest>` taken from the [JUnit Task manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html):

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${build.tests}"/>
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
    </classpath>

    <formatter type="plain"/>

    <test name="my.test.TestCase" haltonfailure="no" outfile="result">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
    </test>

    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.tests}">
        <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
            <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

You can adapt the `<include name=""/>`/`<exclude name=""/>` elements to your needs or add more include/exclude elements. You could then create different ant `<target/>`s for different tests like `<target name="all-tests"/>`, `<target name="package-foo-tests"/>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment yet that's why I am posting this an answer.

I think what you need is a test suite class.

That goes something like follows.

```
package com.emeter.test.predeploy.sdm.common;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

import com.emeter.test.predeploy.sdm.svc.TestOutdatedComponentRpt;
import com.emeter.test.predeploy.sdm.svc.TestSubstationSvc;
import com.emeter.test.predeploy.sdm.svc.TestSvmComponentSvc;
import com.emeter.test.predeploy.sdm.svc.TestSvmNotificationSvc;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({

TestSubstationSvc.class,
TestSvmComponentSvc.class,
TestSvmNotificationSvc.class,
TestOutdatedComponentRpt.class
 }
)
public class TestSuite {

}
```

You can import the required class from any package and then run them all at once. The classes containing the test cases are put under 'SuiteClasses' annotation.

Edit: You just run this like any other test case file in eclipse.